# Which is more efficient? - A single thread and n broadcast receivers OR n independent threads

Tags: android, multithreading, design-patterns, broadcastreceiver

I have a scenario in which 'N' number of independent code snippets need to be run repeatedly in a constant interval. Which one of the following will be more efficient?

1. One thread sending broadcasts repeatedly in a constant interval with N BroadcastReceivers registered for this action.
2. N number of threads running independently and running the code repeatedly.

Or is there a better method?

Comment: Sometimes, I wish those who down vote would add a comment and  would explain why they down voted. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a single background thread but not the methods you're suggesting.
Depending on your scenario:

If the code is to be executed frequently while the app is in the foreground, I would create a Handler associated with a working thread. Then use Handler.postDelayed() to post your work for future execution. When a Runnable finishes execution, it should repost itself.

If the code is to be executed in the background, use AlarmManager to schedule work to be executed by an IntentService and use inexact repeating when possible so that the system will batch background work to save battery life. IntentService will automatically create a single background thread to handle your work and process the Intents in sequence, then stop when it's done.